# Profile Search option in talent solution

Tags: google-cloud-talent-solution

Do we have Profile Search APIs on talent solution?. I can see few documentation but showing as "This is a closed beta release of Profile Search (Beta). We are not accepting new customers into the beta at this time." Do we have a stable version of service for same from google?

Comment: This has been asked many times and unfortunately no answer from the team. Our job board is waiting for this feature to be enabled/available for long otherwise we have to spend extra effort and money to build it.

Answer (score 1):

Profile search is no longer being actively developed.